# Connecting to Hortonworks Hadoop/Hive

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, iccube

I try to establish a connection to Apache Hive. Doing so I used the connection to Impala as a blueprint (http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/ds_hadoop.php). The JDBC driver is installed and the following Setup used:

Driver Type: JDBC
Server Name: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
Db Name: `jdbc:hive2://host:port/database;auth=noSasl`

When I try to establish the connection, IcCube is processing, but it seems not to get anywhere.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Hive and compatible Jdbc drivers. The main task looks as finding the correct jdbc library.

For the hive that is on hortonworks. After a few trials, what worked is drivers - jdbc41 - available on amazon ( [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HiveJDBCDriver.html) ). Take the latest (Hive 0.13.1 JDBC).

- ServerName : com.amazon.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver
- DB Name : jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000

Good luck

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I tried the reccomendations from the Hortonworks website and didn't think, that another company could have working drivers...